# SD card was 32GB, now only 8MB. Won't format

Tags: sd-card

I'm attempting to reformat an SD card in order to use it as a boot drive for NOOBS on my Raspberry Pi. I'm not sure what the card was previously used for, most likely data logging on an old arduino project. It doesn't seem to take to formating and is displaying a significantly reduced size.

I've tried all the methods of fixing an SD card that I know of but this seems to be a particularly stubborn one.

My first attempt to format the card was just by right clicking and selecting 'format'. It only lets me set the size to 8MB and the format fails anyway. Same story using the disk manager and multiple third party SD card formatters.

[image]

Using diskpart didn't work either.

[image: diskpart identifies 32GB SD card as 8MB. Fails to create partion]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SD is **dead** - this is a rare occurrence, but does happen occasionally; I had a brand new Sandisk card which failed in the same way, and was replaced under warranty. There are a few similar reports on this site.

Comment: Well that's sad, it's my only class 10. It didn't occur to me that they could just die without physical damage.

Comment: @griffin175 I wouldn't worry about the card class - the differences relate to block writes; this matters for video, but the Pi uses lots of random access and small writes - you will see no difference between a Class 4 and Class 10.

Comment: @griffin175 what matters for card longevity is whether the card has the necessary circuitry to spread out memory use so that the same area is not being hammered through writing to the same memory locations over and over while other parts of the memory area are not even touched. More expensive cards spread the load doing wear leveling. See https://reprage.com/post/what-are-the-best-sd-cards-to-use-in-a-raspberry-pi